# pickSizeBest() for recursive feature elimination

Tags: feature-selection, caret

I'm struggling providing my recursive feature elimination (RFE) function with valid arguments. This question is technically pretty specific so I hope I've hit the right Forum to ask it.

I want to eliminate features using XGBoost model. According to caret documentation for RFE (http://topepo.github.io/caret/rfe.html#rfe), XGBoost is not provided by default so I need to create custom ctrl$functions (control function for rfe()), which looks something like this:

```
    rfRFE <-  list(summary = defaultSummary,
                   fit = xgbFit    # defined elsewhere using xgboost package
                   pred = function(object, x)  predict(object, x),
                   rank = function(object, x, y) {
                     vimp <- varImp(object)
                     vimp <- vimp[order(vimp$Overall,decreasing = TRUE),,drop = FALSE]
                     vimp$var <- rownames(vimp)
                     vimp
                   },
                   **selectSize = pickSizeBest,**
                   selectVar = pickVars
    )
```

**pickSizeBest()** causes me problems!

When I call the function like this:

```
    example <- data.frame(RMSE = c(1.2, 1.1, 1.05, 1.01, 1.01, 1.03, 1.00),
                  Variables = 1:7)
    cat("Finding the row with the absolute smallest RMSE")
    smallest <- pickSizeBest(example, metric = "RMSE", maximize = FALSE)
```

it works fine (which perfectly makes sense), but what I want is to provide my *train* data and when try to do so (for example, *train[2:127]*), I get this error, for which I haven't found a solution:

```
    Error in `[.data.frame`(x, , metric) : undefined columns selected
```

I know that the syntax for *train* is fine so I have no idea what should I provide to satisfy this function's argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty confusing, but after three days, I know what this simple function is doing!

If you look at `?pickSizeBest` you should see:

```
    - x -> a matrix or data frame with the performance metric of interest
    - metric -> a character string with the name of the performance metric that should be used to choose the appropriate number of variables
```

which basically means you need to provide a name of a variable that is relevant to be considered a metric. In documentation's example data frame, they have a variable called RMSE so the metric is also RMSE, but this can be any variable, it only "picks best size" and what that means is determined with the *maximize* parameter.